# How to post to news feed on facebook through android application

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am working on android application which will have stories fetched from our server.
I want is whenever someone reads a story. A news is posted on facebook like **Ron read *Storyname* on/via *Androidapplication***.
I am still not clear how to define reading either by liking/sharing/recommending.

Forexample, Goodreads or TimesofIndia.

Can anyone tell how to do that ??
I am not asking for code.

Answer (score 0):

The API you want is called Open Graph, you can find the information here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/overview/